# Can you play local co-op on Diablo 3 Starter Edition?

Tags: diablo-iii

Can you play local co-op in Diablo 3 Starter Edition?

Comment: It should say right on the box whether it supports local co-op or not. I know you can't on PC, I assume you are on a console though?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a starter edition on console though...

Answer (score 6):

Diablo III Starter Edition is only available on PC. Local co-op is only available on console versions of Diablo III. So you cannot play local co-op with the Starter Edition, or any version of Diablo III on PC.

Answer (score -3):

Sadly no, the local coop is only for console.
There are other great games to play local like Divinity Original Sin, Gauntlet and  Hero siege.

Comment: @Fredy31 this does provide an answer: "Sadly no, the local coop is only for console."

Comment: This doesn't mention anything that isn't in the other existing answer.

Comment: try to give more information on the subject of the question

Comment: I thought the recommendation would be positive and related to the question. I still don't see a problem with it, I just wanted to help.

Comment: We generally don't like it when people recommend games; the question class itself is off-topic, and it doesn't really answer the question.  Please stick to directly answering the question.